Are the in-order, exactly-once semantics of DynamoDb streams affected by the use of Kinesis Client Library with DynamoDB Streams Kinesis Adapter?
DynamoDb streams have in-order, exactly-once semantics - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html
Kinesis streams do not guarantee this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/kds.html
So, is there a possibility of losing the in-order, exactly-once semantics of a DynamoDb stream if we use KCL with DynamoDB Streams Kinesis Adapter to consume data from it?
